# How can I add to the mongodb connection string in Mule

Tags: mongodb, mule, anypoint-studio

I want to add --sslAllowInvalidHostnames criteria to the mongo connection in Mule but cannot see how I can add this and only see a tick box for SSL.

How can I add this?

**Mongo configuration:**

```
<mongo:config name="Mongo_DB__Configuration" username="${mongodb.username}" password="${mongodb.password}" database="${mongodb.database}" host="${mongodb.host}" doc:name="Mongo DB: Configuration"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The class `org.mule.modules.mongo.Config` (in version 4.1.0, can't confirm for others) simply checks for a system property called `sslInvalidHostNameAllowed` and sets the criteria accordingly.

Try adding `-DsslInvalidHostNameAllowed=true` to your java command used to launch Mule, or alternatively by adding `wrapper.java.additional.<n>=-DsslInvalidHostNameAllowed=true` to your wrapper.conf file (in MULE_HOME/conf) for standalone Mule instances.